# Multiprovider for multiple Tests within one file?

Tags: flutter, testing, widget, dispose

I need to write multiple tests for a widget and I m using a multiprovider for my controller.

The problem is that: the controller is disposed after finishing the first test it can't be called again.

My code at the moment:

```
void main() {

  setUpAll(() {
    setupLocators();
  });


    group('AlertSettingsView-IntegrationTest', () {
      testWidgets('IntegrationTest', (tester) async {
        await tester.runAsync(() async {
          RouteSettings settings = RouteParser().parseRouteParams(settings: const RouteSettings(name: '/alert-settings'));
          await tester.pumpWidget(MultiProvider(
              providers: [
                Provider(
                  create: (_) => locator<UserRoutes>(),
                ),
                ChangeNotifierProvider(
                   create: (_) => locator<AlertController>(),
                )
              ],
              child: MaterialApp(home: Navigator(onGenerateRoute: (_) {
                return PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => AppRouter(settings: settings));
              })
              )
            )
          );
        });
      });
    });

    group('AlertSettingsView-WidgetTest', () {
      testWidgets('WidgetTest', (tester) async {
        await tester.pumpWidget(MultiProvider(
           providers: [
                Provider(
                  create: (_) => locator<UserRoutes>(),
                ),
                ChangeNotifierProvider(
                   create: (_) => locator<AlertController>(),
                )
            ], 
            child: const MaterialApp(home: AlertSettingsView())
          )
        );
      });
    });
}
```

Any ideas how to solve the problem?